# Using MATLAB pcg to Solve Inexactly

Tags: matlab

I am using MATLAB's `PCG` subroutine to solve a system of linear equations. However, I don't want it to solve exactly. I want it to run for only 20 iterations and if it doesn't converge, I want it to return the value at the 20th iteration.
What MATLAB (My version is the latest one) is doing however is returning a zero vector if it doesn't find an acceptable solution by 20 iterations. Is there any way to override this without changing the source code of `pcg.m`?

I have a code which I wrote which does that (I just copied from Wikipedia) but obviously, it is not close to how robust MATLAB's version is.

```
function [x] = conjgrad(A,b,x)
r=b-A*x;
p=r;
rsold=r'*r;

for i=1:20
    Ap=A*p;
    alpha=rsold/(p'*Ap);
    x=x+alpha*p;
    r=r-alpha*Ap;
    rsnew=r'*r;
    if sqrt(rsnew)<1e-10
          break;
    end
    p=r+rsnew/rsold*p;
    rsold=rsnew;
end
```